# Search and finding 10% and 40% values in a column based on last row (maximum) value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a solution to extract data from one workbook to another workbook. I have a workbook "Test data" with one worksheet, (the worksheet name may vary) and I want to extract some data from this workbook to another called "Calculation" by VBA.

What I want is to find the maximum load value from last row, column B and put in workbook "Calculation" with worksheet named "report" cell "S27". Then I want to search through column B and find the 40% load value based on that maximum value, then find the corresponding deformation which is in the same row but column G. These two values should be copied and pasted to calculation workbook (report worksheet) cells N27 and P27.
[image: enter link description here]

The same process as above shall be repeated for 10%. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks on advance!
[image]

Comment: You have highlighted B5 and G4 is that correct ? On the report sheet do you want the loads in cells N27,P27 and the corresponding deformations in cells O27,Q27 ?

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Sorry it Should be B5 and G5! Yes, 10% load in cells N27, 10% deformation in O27, 40% load in cells P27, 40% deformation in Q27. Maximum load (41,3) in S27 but I can change those things if its not straight-ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

I used a file dialogue to choose the data folder and then scan all the files that match a pattern.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub getdata()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Report")
    
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim sPath As String, sFilename As String, iLastRow As Long, iRow As Long
    Dim dMaxLoad As Double, dLoad10 As Double, dLoad40 As Double
    Dim dLoad As Double, dDeform As Double
    
    ' select data folder
    Dim oFileDialog As FileDialog
    
    Set oFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    oFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    oFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    If oFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        sPath = oFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If sPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim oFSO As Object, oFld As Object, iResultRow As Long
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFld = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
    iResultRow = 27
    
    ' get first file
    sFilename = Dir(sPath & "\data*.xls*") ' change pattern to suit
    
    ' scan each file
    Do While sFilename <> ""
    
        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\" & sFilename, False, True)
        Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Sheets(1)
           
        ' determine max load on last row
        iLastRow = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        'dMaxLoad = wsSrc.Cells(iLastRow, "B").Value
        dMaxLoad = WorksheetFunction.Max(wsSrc.Range("B2:B" & iLastRow))
        ws.Cells(iResultRow, "S") = dMaxLoad
        dLoad10 = 0
        dLoad40 = 0
        
        ' scan
        For iRow = 1 To iLastRow
          dLoad = wsSrc.Cells(iRow, "B")
          dDeform = wsSrc.Cells(iRow, "G")
          
          If dLoad40 = 0 And dLoad >= dMaxLoad * 0.4 Then
              dLoad40 = dLoad
              ws.Cells(iResultRow, "P") = dLoad
              ws.Cells(iResultRow, "Q") = dDeform
          ElseIf dLoad10 = 0 And dLoad >= dMaxLoad * 0.1 Then
              dLoad10 = dLoad
              ws.Cells(iResultRow, "N") = dLoad
              ws.Cells(iResultRow, "O") = dDeform
          End If
        
        Next
        wbSrc.Close False
        
        ' get next file
        sFilename = Dir
        iResultRow = iResultRow + 1
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Workbooks scanned = " & iResultRow - 27, vbInformation, sPath

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again, works perfect! I really appreciate if you also help me to find the way to: open another test/workbook, extract new test data from this one and then put them to the next row in "Report"? These tests/workbooks may have been up to 20-30!

Comment: @Ramin Are the workbooks in the same folder and do they have similar names ?

Comment: Ja, they are in the same folder and have similar names.

Comment: Thank you, You're very good at it! I had to change(just googled) Dir(sPath & "\data*.xls*") to Dir(sPath & "\*.xls*") and now works very well.

Comment: Dear Shrivallabha, you may remember the above question for some weeks ago, it seems that the code finds the load on last row regardless of whether it is the maximum load or not. In fact the maximum load may have been next to the last row or 2-3 rows before last row. what should be changed in the code to pick the maximum value in column B ?

Comment: @ramin OK updated code to use WorksheetFunction.Max